# Why is the proxy inside package.json not working in my React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, create-react-app

I am currently trying to perform a simple fetch instruction in my React application, though, the actual url always ends up being that of the React application itself.

The React app is hosted at `localhost:3000`, and the server I am trying to connect to is at `localhost:8080`.

In the `package.json` I have a `proxy` field like so:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

Then I have a fetch somewhere like so:

```
fetch('/', { /* stuff... */ })
```

But when I check in my browser it says a fetch request happened to `http://localhost:3000`; in another application, it used to be that if you had a proxy, this would just go to `localhost:8080`, but not this time.

I tried stuff like deleting the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`, but that did not do anything (also did a npm install afterward). If I do this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080', { /* stuff... */ })
```

The url seems to be the correct one, though I get all sorts of random errors which I just do not understand:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have never heard of CORS, perhaps this is new? So I have two questions really:

1. How to get my React proxy to work?
2. How do I get rid of this CORS stuff? I am running both servers myself so "access control checks" is a whole load of bogus...

Cheers!

Comment: Did you use `create-react-app` to set up your application? Also, are you using React Router Dom?

Comment: I innitialised the project like so: npx create-react-app <name>, and I am indeed using the react router dom, does that mess things up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the proxy to handle a request, the endpoint you are calling shouldn't be handled by your React development server. For example, instead of `fetch('/')`, which is the endpoint that sends your React `index.html` file, your API should be at something like `fetch('/api/')`.

Like the doc [says](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually):

> To tell the development server to proxy any unknown requests to your API server in development, add a `proxy` field to your `package.json`, for example: `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"`.
>
> This way, when you `fetch('/api/todos')` in development, the development server will recognize that it’s not a static asset, and will proxy your request to `http://localhost:8080/api/todos` as a fallback. The development server will only attempt to send requests without `text/html` in its `Accept` header to the proxy.

If it's still not working, you can switch to [configuring the proxy manually](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually), which is the second way to set up a proxy that [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev) talks about.

For that, first, remove the `proxy` you have in `package.json`, keep it as it's the rule for the endpoint I talked about above, then:

```
npm install http-proxy-middleware --save-dev
```

And finally, create a `src/setupProxy.js` file:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api', //  your API endpoint goes here.
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:8080', //  your API URL goes here.
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

With that, you should be good to go. And about CORS, it's not new. You can read about it on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) if you like.

Comment: Hello, tahnks for the answer, I did this, installed the middleware and created the setupProxy file, but now I cannot even see the frontend, that is, if I connect to localhost:3000, I get "this site can't be reached', localhost refused to connect, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. In another of my projects it suffices to just put the proxy field in package.json, then, any fetch to '/' will automatically go to that proxy...

Comment: Without the middleware, changing te endpoint as I said is working?

Comment: Regarding te middleware, make sure `setupProxy` is in `src`, not in any other folder.

Comment: Yes indeed, if I changed the route from '/' to '/api' that works, if I leave it as '/' it falls back to 3000, but a fetch to '/api' goes through to 8080, with the proxy field in package.json though...

Comment: And about your edit, where you ask why you need `/api` for `fetch`, as I said, for the proxy to fire, your React development server shouldn't be able to handle the request. That's how the `proxy` should behave in this case. `/` is handled, as it's the endpoint that sends you your React `index.html` file.

Answer (score 2):

No bro, that's how it's supposed to work. Add a route listener, say "/api", to your server and then call fetch('/api') from the client.

In the browser it will show up as http://localhost:3000/api even though your server is running on 8080.

Comment: Well I suppose it is supposed to work like that, though, it doesn't I have a console.log in the backend that just prints something when a get request is done to '/', when I go to localhost:8080 in my browser, the console.log triggers, though, when I do a fetch in my react app to that address, it goes to port 3000 and return the HTML body from my frontend, the fetch simply does not go through to port 8080